# Create a new collection from an existing one backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, marionette

I have a view that should render models for the player who has the maximum `points` between all the teams. There are many ways to do this but here is the path I am leading down.

```
getMax : function(attribute) {
    return this.collection.max(function (team) {
        //return team.get('players').get(attribute);
        var test = new PlayersCollection(team.get('players'));
        console.log(test)
    }, this);
},
```

This is in a marionette collectionView for teams (well composite, but it works like a collection). I understand why `test` returns the players for each team, but I can't think of a way to merge all the players into one collection then query who is the `max points` leader.

That said I may be able to avoid merging them in the first place if there is a way to determine who is the leader, but since the collection is nested I am a little stumped.

Since `this.collection` are the Teams, I thought something like `this.collection.get('players').get('points')` would allow me to get the max value of all the teams, but that didn't work.

**Weird solution 1** I did a little hacking and came up with this. Alot of problems with this because Its stripped of backbone functionality meaning I cant return the model of the max player, only the points of that player, thats it.. still thinking (brain bleeding lol)

```
teams = App.data.teams

var points1 = teams.get('5368dcc1227a937829b2cb4a').players.pluck('points')
console.log(points1)

var points2 = teams.get('5368dcd9227a937829b2cb4c').players.pluck('points')
console.log(points2)

var test = points1.concat(points2);
console.log(test)

var maxi = _.max(test);

console.log(maxi)
```

**Slightly better solution 2** merging the object arrays

```
teams = App.data.teams

var home = teams.get('5368dcc1227a937829b2cb4a').players.models;
var away = teams.get('5368dcd9227a937829b2cb4c').players.models;

all = home.concat(away);

console.log(all)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
 _.max(this.collection.get('players').pluck('points'));
```

Comment: Ah forgot about the underscore method I used it like that Along time ago let me try using that!

Comment: `this.collection.get(...) is undefined` since my collection is nested I get confused when and where I can use getter methods...

Comment: Oops looks like I accidentally added that inside the .max function, but now all I am getting is infinity returned.. currently checking that out

Comment: what is your `this.collection` if it is a collection of `Player` models, then remove the `.get('players')`

Comment: No I tried in where `this.collection` is the teams collection with players nested inside, I still get ` this.collection.get(...) is undefined`

Comment: Ok, then you need to iterate over your teams collection and for each team you need to get the players collection and `.pluck` the points for each player. Then you can call `_.max` on your collection of points.

Comment: Okay I just did that but it takes me back to square one, I am not trying to get the max within the team I am trying to get the max player out of all the teams..

Comment: Thats why I figured merging all the players into a pool and then querying who is the leader there. but I figured there may be a better way..

Comment: Plus this is already a marionette collection view so the looping of the models is already handled....

Comment: I finally found the proper syntax `this.collection.each(function (team) {
    var points = team.players.pluck('points')
    console.log(points)
}, this);` This gives me an two arrays I think I need to concat the arrays then compare which is the highest.

Comment: I added my solution I played around with in the console I am able to get the max, but I am still wondering if there is a better way? I mean team1 and team2 will have booleans set on them so I can get the ids of the teams set to true, that will be extra work, it's doable but I am still wondering :)

Comment: I think a more elegant solution in concatenating the teams array of player points would suffice

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think I managed to create a somewhat elegant solution, playing in the console can really teach you a lot (highly recommended if you want to get better).

```
teams = App.data.teams

var home = teams.get('5368dcc1227a937829b2cb4a').players.models;
var away = teams.get('5368dcd9227a937829b2cb4c').players.models;

all = home.concat(away);
leaders = new PlayersCollection(all)

function mostPoints() {
    return leaders.max(function(leader) {
        return leader.get('points');
    });
}

mostPoints();
```

Now the function will return the model of the player who has the most points out of everyone, pretty cool!